# How to create issue in JIRA automatically?

Tags: automation, jira

I want to create the issue automatically in JIRA on daily basis for the particular project and issue type.

Please anyone can help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Jira Command Line Interface in a script run on a scheduled basis.
With the CLI you can do something like this example from it's docs:

```
jira --action createIssue --project "zjiraclicustom" --type "bug" --summary "mutli` issue" --field "custom-multi-select" --values "s1,s2,s3"
```

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/org.swift.jira.cli

You may visit:https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/90304/can-jira-be-set-up-to-create-issues-automatically-on-a-scheduled-basis

Comment: Hello friends, any other option apart from this.?